# call NotifyDataSetChanged inside a nested class in my adapter

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I have a listview with a button in it. if i click this button the row it is in needs to be deleted. it "kinda" works, the only thing that is giving me issues is that it does not refresh good. only if i go out and back in the list its gone. or if i flip my screen.
this is the code i have at the moment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using CardAppReal.Lib.Models;
using NavigationDrawerTest;
using Square.Picasso;
using SQLite;
using Path = System.IO.Path;

namespace CardAppReal.Assets
{
    public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Card>
    {
        List<Card> items;
        Activity context;
        public ListAdapter(Activity context, List<Card> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Card this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Layout.CardSavedRowLayout, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.TextCardSavedList1).Text = item.name;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.TextCardSavedList2).Text = item.supertype;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.TextCardSavedList3).Text = item.set;
            Picasso.With(context).Load(item.imageUrl).Into(view.FindViewById<ImageView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.CardSavedImage));
            var imgButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.ImgButtonSaved);
            Picasso.With(context).Load(Resource.Drawable.delete).Into(imgButton);
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Argb(150, 153, 217, 234));
            imgButton.Tag = item.id;
            imgButton.SetOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(this.context, this));
            return view;
        }
        private class ButtonClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
        {
            private Activity activity;
            private ListAdapter adapter;

            public ButtonClickListener(Activity activity, ListAdapter adapter)
            {
                this.activity = activity;
                this.adapter = adapter;
            }

            public void OnClick(View v)
            {
                string name = (string)v.Tag;
                string text = $"{name} Button Click.";
                Toast.MakeText(this.activity, text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                string folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                    "database.db3");
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);
                db.Delete<Card>(v.Tag.ToString());
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i tried giving the adapter to the listener but that does not really work.

Comment: What is the source of data? Is it SQLite DB?

Comment: If you only delete the item in SQLite without deleting the item in `items`. This kind of thing happens.